# AWS assume role for any role in organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have tons of AWS accounts where I want to provide them to a specific resource in one of the accounts, say I have accounts from a to z, and I want all the accounts to access the resource in A.

I created a role that has the policy in account A to access that resource in account A as well, but for the assume policy document, all the online resources are for exposing this role to be assumed by a role in another account, there is no reference about how to make the role assumable by all org accounts altogether.

To make the question more clear and specific, I want the account ID here to be a wild card within an organization:

```
{
              
              "Statement": {
                     "Effect": "Allow",
                     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                     "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/Prod-Xacc-Access"
                 }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to refer to "all accounts in my Organization". You'll need to provide a _list_ of ARNS in the `Resource` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IAM Policy variables. This is an example below I took from [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/restrict-access-by-member-account-to-a-centralized-cloudtrail-logging-bucket/). It allows all accounts in an Organization to do s3:GetObject and s3:ListBucket on an S3 bucket residing on the target account.

During evaluation `${aws:PrincipalAccount}` gets translated to the caller account.
And `${aws:PrincipalOrgID}` translates to the caller account's organization.

```
  {
            "Sid": "MemberAccountAccessObjectLevel",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-organization-bucket/AWSLogs/o-exampleorgid/${aws:PrincipalAccount}/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-exampleorgid"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "MemberAccountAccessBucketLevel",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-organization-bucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-exampleorgid"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "AWSLogs/o-exampleorgid/${aws:PrincipalAccount}/*"
                }
            }
              }
```

Comment: This appears to be an S3 resource policy, attached to the shared bucket. Which, if the OP just cares about S3, is sufficient. But will the same condition work for a trust policy on an assumed role?